# Simple Derivative plus tricky algebraic expression to simplify?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I need to find the maximum of:

$$\frac{(1-e^{-\lambda \tau})}{\lambda \tau}-e^{-\lambda \tau}$$

apply quotient rule to the fraction term

$$\frac{(e^{-\lambda \tau}\lambda \tau-\tau(1-e^{-\lambda \tau}))}{(\lambda \tau)^2}+e^{-\lambda \tau}\tau$$

give common denominator

$$\frac{(e^{-\lambda \tau}\lambda \tau-\tau(1-e^{-\lambda \tau}))+e^{-\lambda \tau}\tau^3\lambda^2}{(\lambda \tau)^2}$$

Is this derivative correct?

I now need to set this equal to zero and solve for lambda!

$$(e^{-\lambda \tau}\lambda \tau-\tau(1-e^{-\lambda \tau}))+e^{-\lambda \tau}\tau^3\lambda^2=0$$

Can this be solved analytically?
Is so could I please have a hint as to how to approach the problem?

Baz

Comment: Differentiating it with Mathematica yields (taking it as a function of $\lambda$):

$$\frac{e^{-\lambda  \tau } \left(\lambda ^2 \tau ^2+\lambda  \tau -e^{\lambda 
   \tau }+1\right)}{\lambda ^2 \tau }$$

Comment: I've compared both functions, and it seems okay. [Here.](http://i.imgur.com/N6XuBKq.png)

Comment: Thanks your expression does seem simpler. As we are equating it to zero only the expression in the brackets remains (right?) I'm still not sure how to solve this as lambda is function of both quadratic and exponential terms?

Comment: Why only the expression in the brackets remain?

Comment: Because to find the maximum you must equate it to zero?

Comment: Wait, what do you mean with *expression in the brackets*? Shouldn't you take $f'(x)=0$ to find the maxima? That is, $\frac{e^{-\lambda  \tau } \left(\lambda ^2 \tau ^2+\lambda  \tau -e^{\lambda     \tau }+1\right)}{\lambda ^2 \tau }=0$?

Comment: Yes but because you are equating to zero you can multiply out the (lambda^2) tau from the denominator and divide out the e^{-lambda tau} from the numerator without affecting the answer

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{(1-e^{-\lambda \tau})}{\lambda \tau}-e^{-\lambda \tau}$$
We see, the function depends on $\lambda\tau$. Set $\lambda\tau=x$ therefore.
$$\frac{(1-e^{-x})}{x}-e^{-x}$$
$$\curvearrowright x\neq0$$
Calculating the extrema:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{(1-e^{-x})}{x}-e^{-x}\stackrel{!}{=}0$$
$$\frac{x^2e^{-x}+xe^{-x}+e^{-x}-1}{x^2}\stackrel{!}{=}0$$
$$x^2e^{-x}+xe^{-x}+e^{-x}-1\stackrel{!}{=}0$$
We see, the function on the left-hand side of the equation is an algebraic equation that depends on $x$ and $e^{-x}$. Both are algebraically independent of each other for all $x$ except $0$. Unfortunately, the equation cannot have therefore a solution that is an elementary function (see [Wikipedia: Elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) for the definition of the elementary functions).

A known special function for inverting functions of $x$ and $e^x$ is the Lambert W function. It is the inverse of $xe^x$. But the function in the equation cannot be represented in the form of equation (1) of my answer at [Algebraic solution to natural logarithm equations like 1−x+xln(−x)=0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578139/algebraic-solution-to-natural-logarithm-equations-like-1-xx-ln-x-0). Unfortunately, the equation cannot be solved with help of Lambert W therefore.

If a function in dependence of a variable in polynomials and in exponential functions cannot be solved with Lambert W, some generalizations of Lambert W function are available. See the references in [Wikipedia: Lambert W function - Generalizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Generalizations) as an entry. Ask if you need further literature references.

The numerical solution for the maximum is

$$\lambda\tau=1.793282132900...,\ f(\lambda\tau)=0.2984256075256...$$

$$\lambda=\tau=1.339134844928...,\ f(\lambda\tau)=0.2984256075256...$$

Comment: What are you using $\stackrel{!}{=}$ and $\curvearrowright$ to mean?

Comment: @ YiFan $\stackrel{!}{=}$ means "should be equal to". $\curvearrowright$ means "from that follows".

Comment: I see, thanks. Is that notation common in your experience? I have never seen either of them before looking at your answer.

Comment: We used this signs in scool and in university (mathematics for natural sciences). Maybe they are non-mathematical signs. See Google: "exclamation mark" "equal sign".

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments and answers, using $\lambda\tau=x$, you want to maximize
$$f(x)=\frac{(1-e^{-x})}{x}-e^{-x}$$ As already said, the derivative is
$$f'(x)=\frac{e^{-x} \left(x^2+x+1-e^x\right)}{x^2}$$ and you then need to find the zero of function 
$$g(x)=x^2+x+1-e^x$$

May be, this could be done using  the [generalization of the Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3999.pdf) with complex coeddicients but I am afraid that this could be a nightmare.

However, we can easily obtain rather good *approximations*.

The derivative 
$$g'(x)=2x+1-e^x$$ cancels for 
$$x_*=-\frac{1}{2}-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{e}}\right)$$ where appears the second branch of Lambert function. At this point (where the first derivative is zero, we can build a Taylor series and get
$$g(x)=g(x_*)+\frac 12 g''(x_*)(x-x_*)^2+O\left((x-x_*)^3\right)$$ Neglecting the higher order terms, the solutions are then
$$x_\pm=x_*\pm  \sqrt{-\frac{2g(x_*)}{g''(x_*)}}$$ In the considered problem, we need to consider the largest solution which is $x_-$.

For more simplicity in notations, let $t=W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{e}}\right) \approx-1.75643$ and then

$$x_-=-\frac{2 t^2+3 t+1+\sqrt{-4 t^3-12 t^2-11 t-3}}{2 (t+1)}\approx 1.90907$$ making  $f(x_-)\approx 0.297958$ which is not too bad when compared to the exact solution @IV_ gave in his/her answer.

Could we do better ? Graphing $f(x)$ we can notice that the maximum is "around" $x=2$. So, using the simplest Padé approximant,w ehave
$$g(x)\simeq \frac{7-e^2+\frac{\left(-36+11 e^2-e^4\right) }{2
   \left(e^2-5\right)}(x-2)}{1+\frac{\left(2-e^2\right) }{2
   \left(e^2-5\right)}(x-2)}$$ which cancel at
$$x=\frac{2+2 e^2}{36-11 e^2+e^4} \approx 1.80051  \implies f(x) \approx 0.298424$$ which is better.

We could continue that way builing around $x=2$ the $[1,n]$ Padé approximants which will write
$$g(x)=\frac{7-e^2+a_1^{(n)}(x-2)}{1+\sum_{k=1}^n b_k (x-2)^n}\implies x_{(n)}=2+\frac{e^2-7}{ a_1^{(n)}}$$
and get the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 n &  x_{(n)} & x_{(n)} \approx & f(x_{(n)}) \\
 0 & \frac{-3+e^2}{-5+e^2} & 1.8371507 & 0.29835622 \\
 1 & \frac{2+2 e^2}{36-11 e^2+e^4} & 1.8005100 & 0.29842369 \\
 2 & \frac{192-98 e^2+28 e^4-2 e^6}{-660+290 e^2-40 e^4+2 e^6} & 1.7943170 &
   0.29842557 \\
 3 & \frac{-12528+8412 e^2-1860 e^4+228 e^6-12 e^8}{21456-11934 e^2+2490 e^4-210
   e^6+6 e^8} & 1.7934191 & 0.29842561
\end{array}
\right)$$